# Picture Transparency

Tags: image, vb6, transparency

How do I make a picture transparent in VB6.0 so that when I add image and put the picture, the background will show behind it?

Comment: What is point of having a transparent picture?

Answer (score 1):

From Rod Stephen's excellent VB Helper site (particularly good on graphics in VB6):

- [HowTo: Overlay one image on another with a transparent color by using PSet](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_overlay_pset.html)

Description from the site:

> This program simply loops through the pixels in the images. For each
>   image in top-to-bottom order, the program looks for a color other than
>   the one defined as transparent. When it finds such a color, it stops
>   looking at the images and sets the output pixel's color using PSet.
>   Note that there are faster ways to access color values in V 6 and VB
>   .NET, and that there are faster methods for merging images if you have
>   an overlay mask. Note also that VB .NET provides tools for setting a
>   transparent color for an image so this problem is trivial in VB .NET.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use an ocx and dll library to fix it

Answer (score -1):

You can use 3rd party .ocx files to get that effect.

checkout this link http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?636390-vb6-Transparent-PictureBox

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Looked again, got an error again, refreshed ...and it worked.
If you edit your answer I can take back my down vote.

Comment: @ClayNichols, What error did you get? The link works fine. If you want, you can suggest an edit. You should only downvote if you believe the answer is not at all useful, not because you had difficulty accessing a link (which works, btw). Maybe you can try a different browser?